# Any way to shut down Java process programmatically but not invoke the JVM shutdown hook?

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

I use `System.exit()`, but it would always call the JVM shutdown hook. How can I shut down a Java process programmatically but not invoke the JVM shutdown hook ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your use case for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()`